# Root of rails application serves wrong kind of file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, mongrel

I am using Ruby on Rails on a CentOS-server with apache 2.0. But somehow the root of the website does not load. It comes up as a download, with the right contents. But it needs to be server as html. Other links within the site are working fine (by adding a text/html type to the .htaccess). Also, when accessing the mongrel directly root does come up. Or when i put a index.html in the public folder of the rails app, it gets loaded as well.

My .htaccess:

```
DefaultType text/html # added for the other pages to get them working, like /products
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteRule .* "http://127.0.0.1:12001%{REQUEST_URI}" [P,QSA,L]
```

Rails version: 2.3.8
Mongrel version: 1.1.5
Apache version: 2.0.63

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to a bug in mongrel_start, it wasn't working properly. [This](https://gist.github.com/471663) fixed the problem. Hope it can be a help for someone else in the future as well.